# error: ld returned 1 exit status during installation

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am still doing the *Caffe Installation* but now I'm facing a new problem. When I run `make` command a new error massage appear which is:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:563: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3'

failed

make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

I am pretty sure I already have all the dependencies.
Hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It can't find the way to reach the files. I mean the files here are `libhdf5_hl.so`, `libhdf5.so` and `libopencv_imgcodecs.so`.

Open your `Makefile.config` file, you'll find the following lines:

```
# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib
```

That means those 3 files I mentioned above are not found within the default `LIBRARY_DIRS`. Search through `usr` subdirectories. 
If you've found the location, for example `/usr/local/hdf5/lib`, then add it to `LIBRARY_DIRS`.

```
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/hdf5/lib
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to create symbolic links to the missing library files. For `hdf5` you may do this:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.10.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so
```

Before creating the symbolic links check the version of your library files and OS. For me it's 10.0.1 and my OS is Ubuntu 15.10.